# How would I do a middleware to catch the user if there is a token and if it does not have a token, to continue without blocking the request?

Tags: laravel, access-token, laravel-passport

I have a "domain.com/v1/campaigns" route that returns a list of data. This route does not need to have a token to access. But if there is a token entered in the header, I'd like to return the user's data. I can not use the "auth: api" middleware because it would make the route always require a token, and that would not be the case. The token on this route would be optional. How would I do a middleware to catch the user if there is a token and if it does not have a token, to continue without blocking the request?

Imagine the situation... I have this route:

**ROUTE**

```
$router->get('campaign/{slug?}', [
    'uses' => 'Controller@getCampaign'
]);
```

This route is public, ie it is not necessary to inform a token in order to list the items. However, if the user is connected, every time he accesses the route, a token is added to the header (Bearer XYZZYZXZ...)

In the controller, I need to get the user's model if there is a token informed, but I can not.

**CONTROLLER**

```
class ControllerPublic extends ApiController
{
    public function getCampaign($slug)
    {

        // THERE IS NO TOKEN IN THE HEADER PRINT USER //
        if (auth()->check()) {
            dd(auth()->user()->toArray());
        }

        $data = $this->call(GetCampaignPublicAction::class, [$slug]);
        return $this->transform($data, CampaignTransformer::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this use Spring or ASP.NET MVC framework? Can you elaborate your middleware a little more? Basically what you need is a filter to intercept the request and customize it to suit your needs.

Comment: The project is in laravel 5.5, where I use an "auth:api" middleware on the route that displays the campaign data. The point is, with this middleware applied, the user is required to inform the access_token, when I would like it to be optional.
But if I take the "auth:api" middleware, I can not use the **auth()->user()** method.

Answer (score 0):

Middleware throws exception if you try to return false from it. So if you tell it to return next $request it goes to next layer. This middleware goes to next layer anyways but it check if there is token available on request query string, if so, try to find user associated with token and when it find user tries to login with that user and then goes to next level.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CheckToken
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @param $role
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->filled('token')) {
            // Find user by using $request->token
            auth()->login($user);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer a little instead of just dropping code.

Comment: This is a problem, find the user by the token. I'm using laravel passport, how would I do it?